# onOptionsItemSelected Not working in fragment backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-optionsmenu

When a fragment added in back-stack, the options menu click is not working. first fragment options item click is worked.

Code for Fragment Backstack

```
public void setFragment(Fragment fragment, int title_res) {
    String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    if (editable_mode) {
        boolean fragmentPopped = manager.popBackStackImmediate(backStateName, 0);
        Log.e("fragmentPopped", fragmentPopped + "");
        if (fragmentPopped) {
            fragmentTransaction.remove(fragment);
        }
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.view_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(backStateName);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    } else {
        boolean fragmentPopped = manager.popBackStackImmediate(backStateName, 0);
        Log.e("fragmentPopped", fragmentPopped + "");
        if (!fragmentPopped) { //fragment not in back stack, create it.
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.view_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title_res);
}
```

Comment: Are you setting the options menu inside your fragment or your base Activity class?

Comment: in base activity

Answer (score 1):

in your fragment onCreate() add this line

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

Update:

If you adding your menu from base activity , then add this code into your fragment onResume() and remove  setHasOptionsMenu(true)  from onCreate()

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(getActivity());
    }
```